# Swift: UITextField upon button press

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I'm working on a trivia app, and currently wondering how to make it so that after the user presses a button, a text field appears where they can type their answer and it can be checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `UITextField` on the page in Storyboard, then in `viewDidLoad` set it to be hidden using `textField.isHidden = true`. Now in the action for your button, set it to be visible, that way when the user presses the button, your `UITextField` will appear

Answer (score 0):

elevate's answer will work but if you wanted to be a bit more fancy you can set the Opacity/Alpha to 0 and when the button is clicked animate the button in (setting the Opacity/Alpha to 1)